# How to unpack a gem from github and specify the branch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, github, rubygems

in my gemfile I use a gem that points to git and a specific branch. How can I unpack a gem in my vendors/gem folder and specify the branch like so?

```
gem 'devise-async', :git => 'git://github.com/mhfs/devise-async.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you executed `bundle install` in your Rails app, you could try the `bundle open devise-async` to open the gem in your editor and then just save it away?

There's also `bundle cache` which caches all the used gems of your app in `vendor/cache`, but I don't know exactly in which kind...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Usually my gems are in my rvm gems directory but when using the above to specify a gem the gem is not downloaded/stored in the rvm gem dir.